# interactive menu can't slide back in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make an interactive menu. It should work like this:

1. If I click on menu-icon the navigation will slide down to visible area (It works)
2. Then If I click menu-icon again the navigation will return back to invisible area again.
   But the second step doesn't work.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menu-icon").click(function(){
       $("#navigation").animate({top: "40%"}),5000;
       $(this).addClass("menu-icon-active").removeClass("menu-icon");
   });
   $(".menu-icon-active").click(function(){
       $("#navigation").animate({top: "-40%"}),5000;
       $(this).addClass("menu-icon").removeClass("menu-icon-active");
   });
   ```

   });

Have got somebody an idea how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can solve your problem by checking within the same click hander if the element has the "active" class, and if so, deactive it, and if not "activate" it.**

Here is a working code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".menu-icon").click(function() {

        if ($(this).hasClass("menu-icon-active") ){

            // menu is active, deactivate it
             $("#navigation").animate({
                top: "10%"
            }), 5000;

            $(this).removeClass("menu-icon-active");

        } else {

            // menu is not active
            $("#navigation").animate({
                top: "30%"
            }), 5000;

            $(this).addClass("menu-icon-active");

        } 

    });
});
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE A FIDDLE OF THIS CODE IN ACTION](http://jsfiddle.net/vqhh3dkb/4/)**

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** jQuery Tip: There is no need for you to add or remove the `menu-icon` class from within your `menu-icon` click handler. That is not needed and will probably give you unexpected or erroneous results. [Thanks to the user @TJ for pointing that out.]

Comment: Why are you adding/removing class `menu-icon`..?

Comment: @TJ You're right, its not nessesary. I was pasting in the original authors code and over looked that. Will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already solved but FYI jQuery has [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods for exactly this sort of thing:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#navigation").hide();//initially hidden
    $(".menu-icon").on("click",function(){
        $("#navigation").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })
})
```

```css
.active {color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#navigation" class="menu-icon">click me</a>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```